# Would this LINQ statement ever return null?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following C# code:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>();

IEnumerable<string> values = from value in source select value;
```

Will `values` ever be null or will it always return an empty sequence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes it CAN** return null if you have an extension method defined in your code somewhere like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Select(this List<string> list, Func<string, string> action)
{
    return null;
}
```

Otherwise no; it will return an empty sequence.

Comment: I don't think that's expected in C# - this would be considered an example of "monkeypatching".

Answer (score 4):

The `values` sequence itself will never be null. If `source` is empty then `values` will be an empty sequence containing no items.

(And, of course, it's possible that one or more of the `string` items in the sequence might be null.)

Answer (score 2):

Linq returns empty sequences
If you want to test if the sequence is empty use the `.Any()` method